# Android memory allocation - StringBuilder

Tags: android, string, memory-management, stringbuilder

I have developed a parser application which receives an input string and then by using regular expression and the output format (all provided by the user) matches the input, replaces backreferences in the output format (using *String.indexOf* and *Strinbuilder.replace()* ) and adds all the results into one **StringBuilder** object. The problem comes when the input string is too big and Android is not able to allocate more memory. What could be the solution for that? Thanks

Comment: Do you need the entire string in one place? Can you save it to a file?

Comment: Which string? The final output? Well, the idea is to show up all the results on the screen.

Comment: What type of content are you parsing? JSON, XML, ...

Comment: You could save the input string directly to disk and then read the string in chunks to reduce the amount of data in memory at any given time.

Comment: @Bobbake4 I thought about it. But after I need to load all data in memory anyway in order for regexp matcher to work, do I?

Comment: It depends on what exactly your trying to match against. You could for instance load a chunk of data that has a matching end tag and run your regex against that, such as <div>...</div>. If your regex only works for an entire file this might not help.